# Hadoop YARN slow resource allocation for Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have this problem where YARN is very slow in allocating resource for spark, sometimes it's late to add executor. This started after a black out, after I restart the cluster, it started acting slow even though I restart it a few times. No configuration were changes. It was working fine before.

[image]

The picture above shows executor were added very late. Sometimes some of the executor were not added at all. The picture below taken before the black out.

[image]

Can anyone figure out what's happening? it's still working, but much-much slower than before.

Comment: What's `spark-submit` of the Spark app? How is the load on Hadoop YARN? It's possible that YARN handles more workload than before?

Comment: @jacekLaskowski i am doing the same experiment and i am the only one who is using the cluster, nothing is changed except for slow allocation resource (YARN is slow adding executors)

Comment: Can you show the Environment tab in web UI and include it to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yarn has Dynamic resource allocation property. I am not sure whether you have enabled this property or not. If enabled means yarn will allocate the resources based on the load.

Comment: i have not enabled Dynamic resource allocation.